# WP_Query orderby meta_value_num not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, post-meta

I'm trying to show list of services by price. I have setup the custom post type and custom fields etc. However, when I run the query on the page the most expensive service (£100) displays first instead of last... The query I've written is below:

```
$services = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'service',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'service_type',
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' => $post->post_name,
    ),
),
'meta_key'  => 'price',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC', ));
```

A link to the page is here [dev.poshwashlondon.co.uk/valeting](http://dev.poshwashlondon.co.uk/valeting).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The entries found on the page you linked seems to be ordered as strings, not numbers. If you cannot cast them to be numbers before querying, then the query must take this into account.

Answer (score 9):

The link you provided clearly shows a string ordering (100, 15, 20, 25, etc.). Your problem seems to be that the meta value the query is using is not a number, but a string.

You can try this:

```
$services = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'service',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'service_type',
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' => $post->post_name,
    ),
),
'meta_key'  => 'price',
'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC', ));
```

You can look at the possible "orderby"s here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Answer (score 5):

I know it's old question, byt maybe my answer will help somebody.

Problem here is that prices are strings as @muka-gergely mentioned, so the sorting will be alphabetical which is fine for strings (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g. 1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might naturally expect).

If you want to sort numbers from lowest to highest you have to add `'meta_type'` to your query

```
$services = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'service',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'service_type',
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' => $post->post_name,
    ),
),
'meta_key'  => 'price',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC', //HERE
'order' => 'ASC', ));
```

Possible values for `'meta_type'` are 'NUMERIC', 'BINARY', 'CHAR', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME', 'UNSIGNED'

For more: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters